Missing geometry when playing B3313 in Parallel Launcher on Steam Deck
When I run B3313 or Mario Builder 64 on my Steam Deck, I'm running into an intermittent issue where many parts of the game are invisible, including Mario, level geometry, and menu backgrounds. I am using the recommended graphics plugin (GlideN64). I was able to run the game fine in the past. I believe the issue started after updating Parallel Launcher and the emulator plugins. Interestingly, I don't have this issue when running with the same settings on my Windows 11 PC.
System Specs:

Parallel Launcher v7.5.3
GLideN64 graphics plugin
B3313 v1.0.1
SteamOS 3.5.19

How do I fix the invisible geometry in B3313?



